# What's a typical playtime for one year of Stardew Valley?

Tags: stardew-valley

The game has an in-game clock but playing on PC I've left it paused for as long as a 24 hour (human) day on a couple occasions.

A full day (6 am - 2 am) is 20 minutes, plus time spent in menu, plus however much time you manage to sink into arcade games. So given 28 day months that would be 37 hours for one year plus menu plus arcade. I'm wondering if anyone has a more faithful measure of total time (sometimes sleeping < 2 am and a realistic amount of time spent in menu).

Comment: I always assumed ~20 minutes for a day (when I do not walk away from the computer).

Comment: Not sure if you are counting every time the game is paused. When talking to someone time is paused. It is also paused when it shows the harvest crops animation, so a full harvest might take 3 minutes of real time but only take 30 minutes game time.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a single example of the relation of in-game time and real time, **I've spent nearly 28 hours in a game year.** According to the in-game clock, I've spent 37:33 through Year 2 Summer 11th, which works out to 151 in-game days, or 18.3 minutes per in-game day.

I don't recall leaving the game running alone for any considerable amount of time. I like to plan what to do on the next day, focusing on doing specific things. I have slept many days before 2 a.m. and many other nearly at 2 a.m.

On [this Steam Discussion](http://steamcommunity.com/app/413150/discussions/0/405693392907487598/), some players say **25, 30 or even 40 hours spent per in game year**. This may not be highly accurate data, being from few players in a game with innumerable gameplay styles and many things to focus and spend time on.

So, if you want more *accurate* and *statistical* data, I would recommend you creating a poll of **in game time vs playtime** on some game discussion forums, asking for personal experiences (I couldn't find much on this online).